# Javascript setInterval not repeating

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to call a function on `onClick` event.

```
var startTime;
var isStarted = false;
var duration;
var loopCount;
var showWarn01 = false;
var showWarn02 = false;
var btn;
```

//above the variables

```
function start1() {

    if (!isStarted) {
        startTime = new Date().getTime();
        isStarted = true;

    }
```

if it started

```
    if (isStarted) {

        duration = 60 * document.getElementById('start').innerHTML;
        loopCount = window.setInterval(function () {
            var leftSeconds = duration - Math.round((new Date().getTime() - startTime) / 1000);

            if (leftSeconds >= 0) {
                var hour = padLeft(Math.floor(leftSeconds / 3600) + '');
                leftSeconds -= hour * 3600;
                var minute = padLeft(Math.floor(leftSeconds / 60) + '');
                leftSeconds -= minute * 60;
                var second = padLeft(leftSeconds + '');
                document.getElementById('showTime').innerHTML = hour + ':' + minute + ':' + second;
            } else {
                window.clearInterval(loopCount);
                confirmButtonDirect.jq.click();

            }
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

setInterval not repeating, only 1 time

Why does it happen so?

Comment: do you see any errors in your console?

Comment: 60 * document.... perhaps you want to use parseInt()

Comment: i need call a function only onclick. when I call onload it works fine But page is refreshed timer is restarted

Comment: Does this work for you? http://jsfiddle.net/k_nut/p3s3n5ed/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem lies in this line:

```
    duration = 60 * document.getElementById('start').innerHTML;
```

If you add a `console.log(duration);` below that line you will see that duration is `NaN`. And since `NaN > <any number>` does not evaluate to true your `if` body is never entered.
Converting it to an integer first solves the problem:

```
    duration = 60 * parseInt(document.getElementById('start').innerHTML);
```

Comment: thanks I tried it still not repeating when I call function start1() at onload it works fine. WHY not working call from onclick I do not know

Comment: Note that the `*` operator converts its operands to numbers, so `60 * "12"` gives you `720` without using `parseInt()` (as in this update to your demo: http://jsfiddle.net/p3s3n5ed/3/).

Comment: @nnnnnn I figured js should be able to convert this on its own. I still think that parsing an integer might be considered better style. But you are right. OPs problem must lie somewhere else...